# Detect if user has logged in

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a php question in the WordPress context. I need the `join` button to only show if if the `(is_user_logged_in())` value is false.

This is my current code:

```
<div align="right"><a href="www.google.com" class="join-button">Join</a>
 |<?php wp_loginout(); ?></div>
```

I would like to modify this code to follow this logic:

```
if user is logged in = false
    display join button 'class="join-button"
else
    do not display join button
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if( ! is_user_logged_in()): ?>
show button
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in

```
<div align="right">
<?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ): ?>
    <a href="www.google.com" class="join-button">Join</a>
    |
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_loginout(); ?>
</div>
```

**EDIT**
because of comment ;)

Comment: Other way round ;) if(!is_user_logged_in()): showButton(); endif;

Comment: @knittl thanks! That worked perfectly :) Is it possible for the '<?php wp_loginout(); ?>' to show with the button instead of just a text link/button?

Comment: @user22507: I guess you have to apply the join-button class to a wrapper span: `<span class="join-button"><a href="…">Join</a> | <?php wp_loginout(); ?></span>`. But I'm just guessing here, I don't know nothing about the styles the join-button class defines.

Answer (score 1):

This didn't work for me either. I found the solution in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in).

```
<?php
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    } else {
        echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
    }
?>
```